# Complex queries in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Let's say we have a entity "**Device**" it contains other entity "**DeviceInfo**", and we have a entity "**Site**" which contains a List of "**DeviceInfo**" entities, and "**DeviceInfo**" has a "**Device**" and a "**Site**" in its properties.

My task was to find all "**Device**"s which are in one "**Site**". To some endpoint I would send a "**Site**" id and page number and size of page (since it has to be pageable). I have made it work by creating a JPA specification

```
public static Specification<Device> bySearchRequest(final DeviceSearchRequest searchRequest)  {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            final Join<Device, DeviceInfo> deviceInfo
                    = root.join(Device_.deviceInfo, JoinType.LEFT);
            final Join<DeviceInfo, Site> site
                    = deviceInfo.join(DeviceInfo_.site, JoinType.LEFT);

            return cb.and(cb.equal(site.get(Site.id), searchRequest.getSiteId()));
        };
    }
```

And then using I would convert the "**Device**"s to "**IndexDevice**"s which is in ES.

```
deviceRepository.findAll(currentUser,
                DeviceRepository.Specs.bySearchRequest(searchRequest),
                new PageRequest(searchRequest.getPage(), searchRequest.getSize()))
                .getContent().stream().map(x ->indexedDeviceConverter.convert(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That is it. It works. But here I am fetching the data from DB, and I already have everything in Elasticsearch. Is there a way to make this same query to fetch the data directly from ES (***with paging***) ?

Only difference is that in ES "**IndexedDevice**" has a direct relation with a "**IndexedSite**" (there is no "**IndexedDeviceInfo**").

**IndexedDevice**

```
{  
  "id":"3eba5104-0c7a-4564-8270-062945cc8f5e",
  "name":"D4",
  "site":{  
        "id":"46e7ada4-3f34-4962-b849-fac59c8fe8ad",
        "name":"SomeSite",
        "displayInformation":"SomeSite",
        "subtitle":""
  },
  "suggest":{  
        "input":[]
  },
  "displayInformation":"D4",
  "subtitle":""
}
```

**IndexedSite**

```
{
   "id": "46e7ada4-3f34-4962-b849-fac59c8fe8ad",
   "name": "SomeSite",
   "displayInformation": "SomeSite",
   "subtitle": ""
}
```

Comment: looks like you can use nested or parent-child relationships in ES. i am not sure untill you can share json schema for each entity?

Comment: you mentioned ES "IndexedDevice" has a direct relation with a "IndexedSite". what is this relation, which is parent-child or has_many. Also please share few usecases of your search query you want to run on such complex document. Please also take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html

Comment: looks like indexeddevice has already embedded indexedinfo?

Comment: Device can only be in one Site at the time. So in SQL it would look something like "SELECT * FROM device WHERE device.siteId = '123'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it. At the end it was really simple. I used ElasticsearchRepository (org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository).

```
elasticsearchRepositoy.search(QueryBuilders.termsQuery
                ("site.id",
                searchRequest.getSite()),
                new PageRequest(searchRequest.getPage(),
                searchRequest.getSize()));
```